# Best way to get summary statistics from datasets I receive daily on a new data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm receiving data daily that's in the same format, and I need to keep track of some summary stats for each day.

This is an example of how I may receive the data

```
Sales_11.23.2020 <- data.frame(State  = c("New York", "New Jersey", "Texas","New Mexico","California",
                               "Kansas","Florida","Alaska","Montana", "Maine"),
                    
                    
                    Units = c(455,453,125,135,135,568,451,125,215,314),
                    
                    Sales = c("20000","12530","51110","54110","65000",
                                  "58220","54612","45102","45896","12510"),
                    
                    Target_Sales = c("20000","20000","55000","50000","65000",
                                        "58000","55000","45000","45000","13000"))

Sales_11.24.2020 <- data.frame(State  = c("New York", "New Jersey", "Texas","New Mexico","California",
                               "Kansas","Florida","Alaska","Montana", "Maine"),


                    Units = c(460,463,165,139,165,668,421,125,205,316),

                    Sales = c("21000","13530","51010","54410","63000",
                                  "56220","57612","42602","43696","12160"),

                    Target_Sales = c("25000","15000","55000","55000","65000",
                                        "58000","55000","47000","45000","13000"))

Sales_11.25.2020 <-  data.frame(State  = c("New York", "New Jersey", "Texas","New Mexico","California",
                               "Kansas","Florida","Alaska","Montana", "Maine"),


                    Units = c(405,353,325,155,235,560,401,125,215,314),

                    Sales = c("20200","16210","51310","56110","65500",
                                  "58225","54602","45602","45806","12410"),

                    Target_Sales = c("25000","22000","55000","50000","65000",
                                        "60000","55000","35000","40000","10000"))
```

And My desired output would be something like this where I can have a column that keeps track of the stats on a daily basis.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `base R` and manipulate data using lists and a function for process. It looks like some variables are defined as factor, so you must format them as numbers and then compute the aggregation values. Here the code:

```
#Code
List <- mget(ls(pattern = 'Sales_'))
#Function
process <- function(x)
{
  x$Units <- as.numeric(as.character(x$Units))
  x$Sales <- as.numeric(as.character(x$Sales))
  x$Target_Sales <- as.numeric(as.character(x$Target_Sales))
  y <- aggregate(cbind(Units,Sales,Target_Sales)~1,x,sum,na.rm=T)
  return(y)
}
#Apply
LL <- lapply(List,process)
#Bind
df <- do.call(rbind,LL)
df$Date <- format(as.Date(gsub('Sales_','',rownames(df)),'%m.%d.%Y'),'%m/%d/%Y')
rownames(df) <- NULL
df<-df[,c('Date','Units','Sales','Target_Sales')]
```

Output:

```
df
        Date Units  Sales Target_Sales
1 11/23/2020  2976 419090       426000
2 11/24/2020  3127 415240       433000
3 11/25/2020  3088 425975       417000
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mget(ls(pattern="Sales_")) %>%
 bind_rows(.id="Date") %>%
 mutate(across(Units:Target_Sales, ~ as.numeric(as.character(.)))) %>% 
 group_by(Date) %>%
 summarise(across(Units:Target_Sales, sum, .names="Total {.col}")) %>% 
 mutate(Date=str_replace(Date, "^.+?_(\\d+).(\\d+).(\\d+)", "\\1/\\2/\\3"))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Date       `Total Units` `Total Sales` `Total Target_Sales`
  <chr>              <dbl>         <dbl>                <dbl>
1 11/23/2020          2976        419090               426000
2 11/24/2020          3127        415240               433000
3 11/25/2020          3088        425975               417000
```